# How to get a filtered list of AWS EMR clusters?

Tags: amazon-web-services, emr

I want to get list of EMR clusters that have a specific tag value. 
I looked up the `ListClusters` API but that does not allow to add custom filters.
How can I apply filter in the API call or implement a two step solution (first get all clusters and then filter them)?

Comment: Since you are calling the API from a programming language, simply filter the result set after it is returned (eg in Python with List Comprehensions).

Answer (score 0):

The service API doesn't expose a tags parameter in the request or response so you would need to first call `ListClusters` and then follow with `DescribeCluster` for every cluster id to expose the tags. An alternative approach would be to embed any tags or data in the cluster name for the list of clusters to be filterable by name after the first step but this is probably not a suitable approach as tags may change.